# Post smiley with text usingAFnetworking

Tags: ios7, afnetworking-2

I m using AFNetworking 2.0 in my iOS application. it's working fine at every stage. I stuck in one problem that how to post smiley with text to update status using Afnetworking. Please help me out if anyone had done this.

Comment: Can you be more specific with smiley? Is it simply emoji characters, or images?

Comment: Emoji things and character aslo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"\ud83d\ude04" is the JSON Unicode escape sequence for U+D83D U+DE04, which is the "surrogate pair" for the Unicode U+1F604 (SMILING FACE WITH OPEN MOUTH AND SMILING EYES).

But NSJSONSerialization decodes this correctly, as can be seen in the following example:

```
const char *jsonString = "{ \"emoji\": \"\\ud83d\\ude04\" }";
NSLog(@"JSON: %s", jsonString);
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithBytes:jsonString length:strlen(jsonString)];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
self.myLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"emoji"];
NSLog(@"Emoji: %@", self.myLabel.text);
```

**Output:**

```
JSON: { "emoji": "\ud83d\ude04" }
Emoji:
```

Comment: I m talking about in build emoji from keyboard.

Comment: You should use your apps smilies i think.see in whatsapp